# XAMPP returning longer URL for $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] than web server

Tags: php, xampp

I am using this code to get part of a URL

```
$artist = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 9, -1);
```

This works fine on my normal website only returning the last part of the URL; however, when using XAMPP on my local machine it is returning the whole, longer URL. Is there a reason for the difference and is there a way I can modify it so they return the same result?

On my website online it returns "Mercury" if the URL is this http://www.saint57records.com/artists/Mercury/ using the below htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/artists/index.php.*
RewriteRule    ^artists/(.+)$    artists/index.php?$1 [L]
```

On XAMPP it returns "ecords/artists/index.php?Mercury" with this URL `http://localhost/saint57records/artists/index.php?Mercury/`, this htaccess isn't working with XAMPP so I have to write it out

Comment: Edit your post with the contents of REQUEST_URI.

Comment: Can you write an example how it looks on your website and on your local computer?

Comment: Just updated with the results

Comment: htaccess works perfectly on xampp, it can be from settings, does in apache.conf allowoverride is on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localhost != saint57records.com
```

Since the .htaccess mod_rewrite rule does not rewrites the urls
`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = "/saint57records/artists/index.php?Mercury/"` on your local xampp installation, so that substr fails.

Check whether you have apache mod_rewrite enabled in your xampp installation.

Comment: I just checked and it is enabled

Comment: allowoverrides enabled? do other rewrite rules work?

Comment: Where do I find allowoverrides

Comment: http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html

be sure to restart your apache